# Yii - Undefined variable error when rendering view

Tags: php, yii

this is my first post.

I'm new to Yii framework.

I'm having a problem now with rendering view.
I get an undefined variable error when I render Controller.

I don't understand why I get an undefined variable error although the variable getting error is surrounded with if statement.

the code below is what I simplified my code that I'm actually working on.

Please help me out!
I'd like to know the reason why Im getting an undefined variable error and also I'd like to know how to solve this problem.

Thanks very much in advance!!!

+++ Controller +++

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $flag = false;

            if($flag){

                $this->render('index', array('test'=>$flag));

            }


        //This causes "Undefined variable:test" Error.
        $this->render('index');

        //This works fine.
        //$this->render('index', array('test'=>$flag));

    }


}
```

+++ View(this is rendered with layout view. +++

```
<?php 
if($test){ 
    echo "$test is false";
}else{
    echo "$test is true";
}
?>
```

Comment: Because `if($test)` still requires a variable to be defined. If you want to test if a variable exists, use `if(isset($test))`.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like `$this->test`

Comment: >DCoder

Thanks, it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fact that you receive an error since attempts to access a `$test` in your View without passing it through the Controllers render is wrong.

You'd pass varible with the rendering function all the time or just check if it is set `if(isset($test))` in your View file.

Cheers!

Comment: <?php 
    if(isset($test)){ 
        echo "$test is false";
    }else{
        echo "$test is true";
    }
    ?>

Comment: But when you write a $variable between doble "", PHP evaluates this variable. And in 'else' when you print: echo "$test is true"; the php displays the value of the variable. Put this between '$test is true' simple.